# Steam package conflict

Tags: apt, package-management, steam

I'm installing Steam on my Acer c720p Chromebook with ElementaryOS.
But I've an issue during the installation. While finalizing the installation at the first launch, Steam installs 3 packages:

- libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
- libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
- libc6:i386

But, i've already these packages but named like:

- libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic
- libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic

And when I continue the installation, it deletes the precedent packages, then at the next reboot, my touchpad doesn't work anymore...
Can someone help me to make steam make the link between my actual version and the one it wants or help me install 32bit version beside the 64bit ?
I hope it's clear.

Comment: This is still an issue in 14.04.3 so it is not off-topic even if the op is running an unoffical spin of Ubuntu.

Comment: @Goddard don't hijack somebody else's question. Ask your own if you must.

Comment: It isn't a hijack.  It is a valid question that was closed for no reason other then the fact it is an un-offical spin.  It still applies to Ubuntu 14.04.3 as I verified.  What work did you do?

Comment: **@Goddard:** We have to draw the line somewhere...  **IgnisMagister:** We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors **so elementary is off-topic here as well.** However, on http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at elementary, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, I fought this issue for a while before I landed on this as a solution:

```
sudo apt-get install steam -y
```

This took care of all of the nasty package issues. Steam started right up.

Comment: Thank you, it works I think that the package from the repository has not the same dependancies that the deb file from the website has. So both my touchpad and steam works. Thank you again.